# Ajax Request - Grab/Load only Div Id

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I want to do an Ajax request that grabs only the ID from a page without loading the entire page, is that possible?  This is how I'm currently doing it now. I can get the information from the ID on the page, however it's loading the entire page including all images from the site thus slowing down the process.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: randomUrl,
       success: function (data) {
           $data.find("#wantedID").html(),
       }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: If you're sure that this is a bottleneck in performance, you may want to create a back-end API for serving only portions of pages. AJAX always loads the entire response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to load the HTML directly into an element in the DOM, use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) to make the AJAX request, so that you can specify a selector for what part of the document you want to load.

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.
>
> ```
> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`
> ```
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `ajax/test.html`, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of `container`. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of `result`, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

In your case you would use:

```
$("#destination").load(randomUrl + " #wantedID");
```

If you need to further manipulate the response, load the response into a hidden DOM element, and then retrieve the HTML from there.

Comment: This would still fetch the entire page, right? Although, as far as I can tell, there is no way to not fetch the entire page.

Comment: @xbonez I think it does have to load the entire page. There may be a way to keep images from loading, but I haven't found an effective way to do that yet.